# How to add attachment to record with REST API without a physical file?

Tags: powershell, rest, servicenow, servicenow-rest-api

I'm trying to use ServiceNow's REST API to add an attachment to a record, but I want to upload the attachment from memory as bytes/base64/etc., without a physical saved file path.

**Currently working when providing a file path**

```
$splat = @{
    URI     = "https://instanceName.service-now.com/api/now/attachment/file?table_name=incident&table_sys_id=$($SysId)&file_name=$($FileName)"
    Method  = "POST"
    Headers = @{
        "Authorization = "Basic $creds"
        "Content-Type" = "text/plain"
    }            
    InFile   = "C:\Users\Me\Documents\test.txt"
}

Invoke-RestMethod @params
```

**Desired**

In my mind it would be something like this,

```
$fileContent = "This is the file content to upload"
$file = [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($fileContent)

$splat = @{
    URI     = "https://instanceName.service-now.com/api/now/attachment/file?table_name=incident&table_sys_id=$($SysId)&file_name=$($FileName)"
    Method  = "POST"
    Headers = @{
        "Authorization = "Basic $creds"
        "Content-Type" = "text/plain"
    }            
    InFile   = $file
}

Invoke-RestMethod @params
```

I've found a few questions that I believe are similar, but I can't understand the language used, and how to convert it to something I do know (PowerShell/Python) :D

[Upload Attachment to ServiceNow using SOAP and Base64 via BluePrism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57862584/upload-attachment-to-servicenow-using-soap-and-base64-via-blueprism)

https://www.servicenow.com/community/developer-forum/inserting-attachments-in-servicenow-from-jira-without-mid-server/m-p/1737949/page/4

https://www.servicenow.com/community/developer-forum/insert-attachment-in-servicenow-from-3rd-party-with-base64-and/m-p/1446849

**Also**

In the [docuemntation](https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/tokyo-api-reference/page/integrate/inbound-rest/concept/c_AttachmentAPI.html), there are 2 different endpoints

- Attachment - POST /now/attachment/file
- Attachment - POST /now/attachment/upload

The "upload" endpoint description reads

> Uploads a multipart file attachment.

Does it matter which endpoint to use? What is a multipart file?